# perl XML setting tag value issue

Tags: xml, perl

I have some code that creates XML differently based on a very simple string of characters.  Does anyone know why?

First of all, code snippet ( to clarify things for @mob ), with the lines AROUND the problem line:

```
my $XML = XML::Smart->new();

my $mylogin = {
    userId => $SQLUser,
    password => $SQLPass,
    maxIdle => '900000',
    properties => '<hidden for privacy concerns>'
};
$XML->{'System-Link'}{Login} = $mylogin;

my $request = {
    sessionHandle => '*current',
    workHandle => '*new',
    broker => 'EJB',
    maxIdle => '900000'
};
$XML->{'System-Link'}{Request} = $request;

my $querylist = {
    name => 'queryListPurchaseOrderItemRelease_SLTOKEN',
    domainClass => '<hidden for privacy concerns>',
    includeMetaData => 'true',
    maxReturned => '1'
};
$XML->{'System-Link'}{Request}{QueryList} = $querylist;
### PROBLEM LINE GOES HERE, just subsitute one of below lines here

## Muck with the DTD cause 'EMPTY' causes problems, this is an issue w/ the implementation of XML::Smart
open $dtd, '<', 'SystemLinkRequest.dtd';
my $dtdContent = do { local $/; <$dtd> };
close $dtd;
$dtdContent =~ s/EMPTY//g;

$XML->apply_dtd($dtdContent);

## Turn off output of DTD and meta tag generation
my $xmldata = $XML->data(nometagen => 1, nodtd => 1);
$xmldata =~ s/\?>/?>\n<!DOCTYPE System-Link SYSTEM 'SystemLinkRequest.dtd'>/m;
## Store a clean version (no passwords) in the local XML file
my $xmldata_clean = $xmldata;
$xmldata_clean =~ s/userId\s*=\s*\"$SQLUser\"\s+password\s*=\s*\"$SQLPass\"/userId=\"REMOVED\" password=\"REMOVED\"/g;

my $xml_filename = $RELEASE . "-" . time . ".xml";
print LOGF "{DEBUG} [" . localtime(time) . "] \tBuilding XML Request COMPLETED\n";
print LOGF "{DEBUG} [" . localtime(time) . "] \tWriting XML Request to Request_$xml_filename STARTED\n";

open $RequestLogfile, '>', "$logsDir/XML/Update/Request_$xml_filename";
print $RequestLogfile "\n--------------- QUERY REQUEST ---------------\n";
print $RequestLogfile $xmldata;
close $RequestLogfile;
```

Works:

`$XML->{'System-Link'}{Request}{QueryList}{Pql} = "SELECT order,line,item,release,dueToDockDate,dueToStockDate,userFieldAmount1 WHERE (releaseStatus < '50' AND userFieldAmount1 = '$RELEASE' AND relatedQueryPurchaseOrder.orderStatus < '40' AND remainingQuantityForReleaseStockingUm > 0.000) ORDER BY order,line,release";`

Does not work:

`$XML->{'System-Link'}{Request}{QueryList}{Pql} = "SELECT order,line,item,release,dueToDockDate,dueToStockDate,userFieldAmount1 WHERE (releaseStatus < '50' AND userFieldAmount1 = '$RELEASE' AND relatedQueryPurchaseOrder.orderStatus < '40') ORDER BY order,line,release";`

Now the XML I get.

Good XML ( Pql tag with CDATA ):

```
<QueryList domainClass="com.mapics.pm.PoItemRelease" includeMetaData="true" maxReturned="1" name="queryListPurchaseOrderItemRelease_SLTOKEN">
<Pql><![CDATA[SELECT order,line,item,release,dueToDockDate,dueToStockDate,userFieldAmount1 WHERE (releaseStatus < '50' AND userFieldAmount1 = '4001166' AND relatedQueryPurchaseOrder.orderStatus < '40' AND remainingQuantityForReleaseStockingUm > 0.000) ORDER BY order,line,release]]></Pql>
</QueryList>
```

Bad XML ( Pql attribute ):

```
<QueryList Pql="SELECT order,line,item,release,dueToDockDate,dueToStockDate,userFieldAmount1 WHERE (releaseStatus &lt; '50' AND userFieldAmount1 = '4001166' AND relatedQueryPurchaseOrder.orderStatus &lt; '40' ) ORDER BY order,line,release" domainClass="com.mapics.pm.PoItemRelease" includeMetaData="true" maxReturned="1" name="queryListPurchaseOrderItemRelease_SLTOKEN"/>
```

The only difference between the two lines of code is that the one that works has `AND remainingQuantityForReleaseStockingUm > 0.000`

So why does that impact the resulting XML?

Comment: You forgot to include the code.

Comment: What I provided is the problem code snippet, the exact code that has the problem.  What else can I provide to help?  I was trying not to bog down the question with lots of code, keeping it simple.

Comment: That code is just an assignment that updates a data structure. You did not describe how your data structure is converted to an XML document. You did not even describe which of the many available XML modules you are using.

Comment: Done.  What I don't understand is why simply adding "AND remainingQuantityForReleaseStockingUm > 0.000" to the assignment fixes the resulting XML.  Hope I provided enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`XML::Smart::_data_type`](https://metacpan.org/source/TMHARISH/XML-Smart-1.78/lib/XML/Smart.pm#L1107) contains this code:

```
  return 3 if( $data && $data =~ /<.*?>/s    ) ;
```

where data type "3" indicates that the XML element should be rendered as CDATA. If that is the "good XML", it is only that way on accident.

I guess you could trick `XML::Smart` into rendering all your SQL queries as CDATA with an extra clause like

```
SELECT ... WHERE (... AND ... AND 1<>0) ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Also, for anyone curious, obviously using "1 > 0" works in my case as well.  I used that on the extreme off chance the other system I am talking to uses some weird version of SQL that does not treat "<>" as not equal.  Unlikely, but better safe than sorry and works in my case, producing "good" XML.  But mob idea did work excellently, so I approved his solution.